# Injective homomorphism from extension field to complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be irreducible in $F[x]$, where $F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $c$ be a complex root of $P(x)$. Let $h:F\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an injective homomorphism. If $\deg P(x)=n$, I would like to show that there are exactly $n$ injective homomorphisms $F(c)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which are extensions of $h$.

$P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $c$, since it's irreducible.

If there are to be $n$ injective homomorphisms, it's likely that $h$ takes $c$ to some root of $P(x)$. But why must that be the case? (Why can't $h$ take $c$ to something else in $\mathbb{C}$?)

Comment: Incidentally, assuming you require your homomorphisms to take $1$ to $1$ (as is usually required in commutative algebra), then _every_ homomorphism of a field is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the $n$ injective homomorphisms $F(c) \to \mathbb{C}$ extending $h$ are precisely given by sending $c$ to a complex root of $Q = h(P)$ (extending $h$ to a map $F[x] \to \mathbb{C}[x]$), of which there are $n$ (since $Q$ is irreducible over a separable field). The reason: write $P(x) = a_nx^n + \ldots + a_0$. Since $c$ is a root of $P$,

$$a_nc^n + \ldots + a_n = 0$$

If $\varphi : F(c) \to \mathbb{C}$ is any field homomorphism extending $h$, then applying $\varphi$ to both sides of the above gives

$$0 = \varphi(a_nc^n + \ldots + a_n) = \varphi(a_n)\varphi(c^n) + \ldots + \varphi(a_0) = h(a_n)\varphi(c)^n + \ldots + h(a_0)$$

i.e. $\varphi(c)$ is a root of $Q$. From a slightly higher viewpoint, being a root of a polynomial just means satisfying an equation using only addition and multiplication, and ring homomorphisms by definition preserve both, so any ring map acting as the identity on coefficients must send roots to roots (this is a main idea in Galois theory).

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have $\varphi(a_i)=h(a_i)$. But of course you can assume without loss of generality that $h$ is the inclusion mapping. On the other hand, it remains to be shown that a mapping sending $c$ to another root of $F$ is, in fact, an injective homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we know that $h(a_i)=a_i$? I thought it's not supplied in the problem statement.

Comment: I realized that immediately after posting, and have updated the answer